# why plugin built via Tycho working with JDT but not CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, tycho

I am so frustrated when trying to find out the reason why the Eclipse plugin I built via Tycho is not working in CDT, but working in JDT.
The parent pom.xml looks like the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company.eclipse.plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>abc-master</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <name>abc Master</name>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

   <modules>
    <module>../abc</module>
  </modules>

  <properties>
    <tycho.version>0.20.0</tycho.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <kepler-repo.url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler</kepler-repo.url>    
  </properties>

  <repositories>

    <repository>
      <id>kepler</id>
      <url>${kepler-repo.url}</url>
      <layout>p2</layout>
    </repository>

    <repository>
      <id>cdt</id>
      <url>http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/kepler</url>
      <layout>p2</layout>
    </repository>   
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho.version}</version>

        <configuration>
        <resolver>p2</resolver>
        <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
          <environments>
             <environment>
              <os>linux</os>
              <ws>gtk</ws>
              <arch>x86</arch>
            </environment>
            <environment>
              <os>linux</os>
              <ws>gtk</ws>
              <arch>x86_64</arch>
            </environment> 
            <environment>
              <os>win32</os>
              <ws>win32</ws>
              <arch>x86</arch>
            </environment>
            <environment>
              <os>win32</os>
              <ws>win32</ws>
              <arch>x86_64</arch>
            </environment> 
            <environment>
              <os>macosx</os>
              <ws>cocoa</ws>
              <arch>x86_64</arch>
            </environment> 
          </environments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>


      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>p2-composite</outputDirectory>
              <resources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>p2-composite-template</directory>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>   
    </plugins>

  </build>

</project>
```

And the pom for abc plugin looke like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <relativePath>../abc-master/pom.xml</relativePath>
    <groupId>com.company.eclipse.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc-master</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </parent>


  <artifactId>com.company.eclipse.plugin.abc</artifactId>
  <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

</project>
```

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: And what does error log say?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? If you want good answers, you have to ask specific questions with relevant details. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is no log in .meta/.log file in the workspace. There is no error in console as well.
Not working means the plugin seems not installed.

Comment: Hi friends,
thanks a lot for helping me.
I suspect it is due to the Eclipse for C/C++ is somehow corrupted. So I download a new CDT, and copy the files from the new CDT to old CDT folder by folder, and try start the old CDT to see if the plugin works. After I replaced the "configuration" folder using new downloaded copy, the plugin works. So means something in the configuration folder in the old CDT prevent the plugin from starting.

Unfortunately I forgot to backup the old CDT, so now I am not able to re-product the issue to investigate what is wrong in configuration folder.

Comment: In this case, this question can be closed as "cannot reproduce"

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for helping me. I suspect it is due to the Eclipse for C/C++ is somehow corrupted. So I download a new CDT, and copy the files from the new CDT to old CDT folder by folder, and try start the old CDT to see if the plugin works. After I replaced the "configuration" folder using new downloaded copy, the plugin works. So means something in the configuration folder in the old CDT prevent the plugin from starting. Unfortunately I forgot to backup the old CDT, so now I am not able to re-product the issue to investigate what is wrong in configuration folder.

Closed as cannot reproduce